# Как посчитать кол-во не подключенных и проблемных устройств?

Tags: c#, winapi, циклы, foreach

[image: Снимок]

На фотографии видна часть,  но я все таки скопирую код сюда :

```
ManagementObjectSearcher Devices =
new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\CIMV2", "SELECT * FROM Win32_PnPEntity");
foreach (ManagementObject mo in Devices.Get())
{
ConnectedDiveces += "\r\n" + "---------------------------------------------------------" + "\r\n" + 
"Name: " + mo["Caption"] + "\r\n" + "ID: " + mo["DeviceID"] + "\r\n" + "Manufacturer: " + 
mo["Manufacturer"] + "\r\n" + "Plug and Play: " + mo["Present"] + "\r\n" + "Status: " + mo["Status"];
}
```

Так я достаю всю информацию о подключенных девайсах на материнской плате. То ли мозги вскипели, не знаю, не могу сделать.

1. Мне нужно посчитать кол-во всех подключенных устройств в цифрах.
2. Нужно найти те устройства, у которых Status != OK и Present = FALSE и выдать отдельно только их. И + к этому отдельно посчитать и выдать их кол-во ( то есть кол-во проблемных устройств )

Спасибо вам заранее большое за помощь!

Comment: `"---------------------------------------------------------"` можно заменить на `new string('-', 50)`

Comment: Я немного не понимаю в чем проблема. Допустим если у вас признак подк. устр -  Status == "OK" сделайте некую переменную счетчик и через if посчитайте в нее и т.п.. Не понятно в чем конкретно проблема. Уточните плиз.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно этот код Вам поможет

```
        ManagementObjectSearcher Devices = new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\CIMV2", "SELECT * FROM Win32_PnPEntity");
        var allDevices = new List<string>();
        var defectiveDevices= new List<string>();
        foreach (ManagementObject device in Devices.Get())
        {
            var deviceString = "\r\n" + "---------------------------------------------------------" + "\r\n" +
            "Name: " + device["Caption"] + "\r\n" + "ID: " + device["DeviceID"] + "\r\n" + "Manufacturer: " +
            device["Manufacturer"] + "\r\n" + "Plug and Play: " + device["Present"] + "\r\n" + "Status: " + device["Status"];
            allDevices.Add(deviceString);

            if(device["Status"] != "OK" && device["Present"] == "FALSE")
            {
                defectiveDevices.Add(deviceString);
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine($"Total devices: {allDevices.Count}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Total defective devices: {defectiveDevices.Count}");
        Console.WriteLine();
        foreach(var defectiveDevice in defectiveDevices)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(new string('-', 50));
            Console.WriteLine(defectiveDevice);
        }
```

Comment: А в самом запросе можно написать `SELECT * FROM ... WHERE Status != 'OK'`?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov возможно если ненужно выводить все устройство. Но нужен будет еще один запрос на подсчет кол-ва устройств сделать

Comment: Спасибо большое! это точно то , что было нужно. Голова вскипела и уже мозги не варили :D Спасибо!